How to select the row with specific condition and the row just above?
Here is how I defined my condition , but I need the row just above as well. There are many observations per ID.
data2<- data2 %>% 
  group_by (ID_number)  %>%  
  filter(time_diff_hour > 8.000 | is.na(time_diff_hour))


You don't have to yell at us.. Please have a calm read on how to provide a reproducible example, and edit your question to include it.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

I think you want either idx = which(ave(data$time_diff_hour, data$id, FUN = \(x) x>8L | is.na(x))==1L); data[sort(unique(c(idx, idx-1L))), ] |> `rownames<-`(NULL) or  by(data, ~id, \(X) { idx = which(X$time_diff_hour>8L | is.na(X$time_diff_hour)) ; X[sort(unique(c(idx, idx-1L))), ] }) |> array2DF() |> _[-1L] |> `rownames<-`(NULL) .

For data like data = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), time_diff_hour = c(NA, 9, NA, 3, 8, 4, 2, 9, 10, NA)), row.names = c(7L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 6L), class = "data.frame")

You can add filter conditions with the lead function, which will return a row above the tested row. In opposite, if you need to return a row below the tested row, you can use the lag function.
data2<- data2 %>% 
  group_by (ID_number)  %>%  
  filter(time_diff_hour > 8.000 | is.na(time_diff_hour) | 
         lead(time_diff_hour) > 8.000 | is.na(lead(time_diff_hour)))


Here is a solution in base R:
# Generate a sample data frame
data2 <- data.frame(ID_number = rep(factor(sample(1000:9999, 10, replace=TRUE)), 4),
                 time_diff_hour = sample(c(NA, 4:12), 40, replace=TRUE))

# Find indices matching the criteria
i <- which(data2$time_diff_hour > 8 | is.na(data2$time_diff_hour)) # initial matches
i <- sort(unique(c(i, i-1))) # combine initial matches with previous rows
i <- i[i %in% seq_along(data2$time_diff_hour)] # to ensure only valid indices are used (i.e. for case where a match is generated in row #1)

data2[i, ]

I realise this is quite clunky (if this can be simplified/shortened, please let me know!) - one of the reasons why we have dplyr/tidyverse...
